# use assert in prolog with a fact does not declerad

Tags: prolog

I am completely new using prolog

I want to get the result from `f` and put it in a new fact without duplicated

```
f(1,2).
f(1,3).
f(1,10).
f(9,1).

get(X,M):-
    (f(X,W);f(W,X)),
    (not(fff(W)),not assert(fff(W)));fff(M) .
```

it is not working `Unknown clause found fff(2)`
but when I tried to put `assert(fff(-1))` on the first line on `get` worked but it is not the best solution

anyone can give me a better way to declared a `fff`

Comment: What is fff?  You only define the predicates `f` and `get`.

Comment: `fff` is a dynamically fact contain the result

Comment: *...worked but it is not the best solution* - could you define what you mean by "best"?

Comment: in my solution add a new value does not exist in fact -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is not very clear, because `M` and `W` are both free variables. I *assume* the goal is something like:

> get the M of X such that f(X,M) or f(M,X), and memoise the value of M using the dynamic predicate `fff`.

Assuming I got that right, my solution would be:

```prolog
:- dynamic( fff/1 ).

f(1,2).
f(1,3).
f(1,10).
f(9,1).

get( X, W ) :-
  f( X, W ),
  assert_fff( W ).
get( X, W ) :-
  f( W, X ),
  assert_fff( W ).

assert_fff( W ) :-
  fff( W ),
  !.
assert_fff( W ) :-
  asserta( fff( W ) ).
```

Output:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (Multi-threaded, 64 bits, Version 5.10.4)
Copyright (c) 1990-2011 University of Amsterdam, VU Amsterdam
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Please visit http://www.swi-prolog.org for details.

For help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?- consult('test.pl').
% test.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 2,440 bytes
true.

?- listing(fff).
:- dynamic fff/1.

true.

?- get(1, W).
W = 2 ;
W = 3 ;
W = 10 ;
W = 9.

?- listing(fff).
:- dynamic fff/1.

fff(2).
fff(3).
fff(10).
fff(9).

true.

?-
```

Comment: thank you, but when I reconsult get this message `PIE syntax error at position 3: Unexpected token: atom("dynamic")`

Comment: I am using `prolog inference engine`

Comment: Different versions of Prolog are slightly different. The output above is from SWI Prolog. If the `:- dynamic` directive doesn't work on your Prolog version, then try leaving it out. If that doesn't work, look at the documentation for your version to see how to declare a predicate to be dynamic.

Comment: The ISO Prolog standard doesn't require `dynamic` to be an operator. Does the problem go away if you change the first line to `:- dynamic(fff/1).`?

Comment: maybe `dynamic` not a keyword :(

Comment: @motaz: `dynamic/1` is part of the ISO standard, but, as @PauloMoura points out, it's not necessarily an operator. I've updated my answer having tested the code on GNU-Prolog as well as SWI-Prolog. Note that I also changed `assert` to `asserta`. If this code still doesn't work for you, you'll need to tell us which version of Prolog you are running.